# ASP.NET core MVC how to use dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, razor-pages

Im trying to make dropdown list in my razor view using Viewbag but its not working, Im missing something I guess

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllEmployeeForPayroll()
        {
            return GetAll().Select(emp => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = emp.FullName,
                Value = emp.Id.ToString()
            });
        }
```

ViewBag.employees = _employeeService.GetAllEmployeeForPayroll();

```
                <label asp-for ="EmployeeId"></label>
                <select asp-for="EmployeeId" class="form-control" asp-item="ViewBag.employees">
                    <option selected >---Select Employee---</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for ="EmployeeId" class="text-danger"> </span>
```

this is my code Im sure I did something wrong in razor view but cant figure out what.`enter code here`

Comment: Please specify the error, expected output in detail.

Comment: there is no any kind of error this just don't work as expected. this select with options command suppose to do dropdown list but it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answer your question regards.

```
<div class="row">  
    <div class="col-md-4">  
        <select id="drpEmpList" class="form-control" asp-for="EmployeeId" asp-items="@ViewBag.employees">  
            <option value="">--Select--</option>  
        </select>  
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="EmployeeId" />  
             
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use foreach()

```
<label> Select Employee </label>

        <select class="form-control">
            @foreach (string item in ViewBag.employees)
            {
                <option value="@item">@item</option>
            }
        </select>
```

I hope it's be usefull

Answer (score 0):

It should be [`asp-items`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-select-tag-helper) but not `asp-item`.

```
<select asp-for="EmployeeId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.employees">
  <option selected >---Select Employee---</option>
</select>
```